# How to kill a Spiketor?

Tags: rogue-legacy

In Rogue Legacy there are these bouncing balls of dooooom that are fairly familiar form all video games in ages past. I have seen them die by hitting walls to many times but this is mostly just the ones that are moving vertically. They do show up as enemies when you have the good memory trait, but is there a way to actually kill them??? Is just watch them bounce the only way?

Answer (score 17):

If you have a retribution rune equipped, they will deal damage to themselves as they hit you. This can destroy them, which gives you a chance to get gold just like killing any other enemy.

There is no way to actively damage them without a little self-sacrifice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 15):

After some testing, it seems that the spiketors die if they have two consecutive bounces in a short amount of space travelled in the interval between them.

This would prevent situations where a spiketor is bouncing in a narrow pathway, preventing passage as the character model isn't small enough to fit through the space in the passageway that the spiketor isn't touching.

Comment: I always wondered why they would randomly self-destruct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they have a set limit of "bounces" before they die.  I've been in rooms that had them traveling a very narrow path (multiple bounces per second) and after a few seconds they went "poof" and died.  I wish I had a more specific answer, but its something to look into.

Comment: I don't know if this is an absolute limit or a timed limit. I think they only die if they get a certain number of bounces over a short period of time. Balls that travel a further distance between bounces seem to last forever.

Comment: @StrixVaria I'm pretty sure you're right - I saw one get trapped in one of the invisible hidden chest areas and it died within a few seconds. There might be a maximum time for the long-bounce ones but it would probably be far too long to ever wait for it.